# Where do we tell users not to use Pastebin?

Tags: discussion, external-links

I assume that people asking questions should not be using Pastebin, because:

- [Its license doesn't match SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/425670)
- Questions should be self contained.

I just asked a user not to use Pastebin (they had put 50 lines of error message there), and they said that they thought it was allowed. Looking at ["How to ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) we only tell users not to post text as images, and say that code should be in the question.

Is there something they should have read before asking a question which would have explained that they should not use Pastebin for *any* text, for the two reasons above?

Comment: People shouldn't use Paste Bin because if Paste Bin isn't available in the future the question is *useless*. The content of the question should *be in the question*.

Comment: We do, poorly. in the new editor: *"Links to pastebin.com must be accompanied by code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon."* Presumably if the question body already contained code they'd just not get this error.

Comment: The license doesn't need to match, post authors can license their own content under whatever license they want; but the going guidance dictates that questions need to be self-contained. It's less "don't use Paste Bin" and more "always include everything in the question", even if you _do_ link to Paste Bin.

Comment: This FAQ is in the ballpark, though it's about linking a live, online project rather than Paste Bin; the guidance still feels pretty applicable, however: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428)

Comment: related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/339450/11107541, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277891/11107541, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274649/11107541

Comment: The problem is people are not looking on meta before they ask their first questions because they don't know meta is a the oral history of Stack Overflow and a trove of great wisdom. Hell, they probably won't even know meta exists until they're directed to meta when they get Q-banned, and that doesn't serve the asker any better than it does Stack Overflow and its community.

Comment: @user4581301 I imagine most don't even read "How to ask" (I wonder if stats exist on that?)

Comment: Considering the number of times I've linked to `[mre]` only to have the asker respond by adding the complete program or code butchered to the point that it can't possibly compile in order to make it shorter, I'd say the odds of the link having been read are generally quite low even when you point the asker right at it.

Comment: But my point is this stuff needs to be called out early and unambiguously to the asker early and often. If they miss the information that'll make them useful members of the community, or at least keep them from getting banned, after you jam it right in their face, there's nothing you can do to help. But right now a lot of that information is buried in a decade-and-a-half of meta where I don't expect anyone to find it before they're told about it.

Comment: I'm decently sure pastebin *is* allowed, just as linking to GitHub, or documentation, or the personal homepage of Santa Claus. It's just that this is *extra* information - the question is the question, and it has to work without people being able or willing to dig up that extra information.

Comment: I'd say the second bullet point under _"Help others reproduce the problem"_ on [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) covers it pretty well: _"If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to (for example, on http://sqlfiddle.com/ or http://jsbin.com/) then do so—but also copy the code into the question itself. Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time. Use Stack Snippets to make a live demo of inline JavaScript/HTML/CSS."_

Comment: Separate from compliance with policies that questions need to be self-contained -- pastebin.com _in particular_ has a history for not vetting its advertisers carefully (it was full of animated, annoying banners for oft-shifty products and services back in the day when I had a different moral take on adblockers than I do now). They may well be better about this today than they were 15 years ago, but unless an ownership change accompanied this change, I wouldn't be surprised for ads to be occasionally malware-carrying (even with no active knowledge/collusion, just from lack of vetting).

Comment: Related: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4518341) This covers related points like *"code (or errors/exceptions, logs, configuration, ..."* and *"URLs often become stale and unavailable, breaking future ability to read the post."*

Answer (score 31):

All questions on SE **must** be self-contained. If the OP can't (or won't) reduce the code (and data) required for a question to a MRE, then their question is just not suitable for SO.

The problem is that it's often hard to get new members to understand this. They expect SO to be a help-desk / discussion forum, and they simply don't get that we're trying to build a Q&A library.

So even if they *do* take the Tour, and read the relevant Help pages, and perhaps even some FAQs on MSO / MSE, it may still not sink in that we aren't a help-desk and that their question has to be crafted so that it fits our Q&A library format.

IMHO, the existing Help pages do a reasonably good job of explaining the requirements of a suitable SO question. But if the OP has the help-desk mentality, it doesn't matter what Help pages etc they read. It can be hard enough trying to explain this stuff in an actual conversation in the comments or a chatroom. OTOH, it's certainly useful to have these requirements listed in an easy-to-find Help or FAQ page.

Once the OP understands the Q&A library principle, then it's easy for them to understand why question code must be a MRE. If they want to link to their full code on pastebin, or Github, etc, that's fine. But they need to realise that it's just supplementary information, and that their question has to be understandable (and answerable) without that supplementary information.

Answer (score 13):

Using pastebin or similar sites really isn't the problem on its own (pastebin particularly is often unnecessary though other sites that add additional functionalities exist). As it is allowed, there is no place on the site that tells you not to use it.

The problem is **only** using an external site and not posting the code within the question.

["How to ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) repeatedly tells people to:

- > **Include** just enough code
- > copy or type the text **into the question**
- > make sure you can *[reproduce the problem]* using only the information **included in your question**

<sub>(Emphasis mine)</sub>

And specifically:

- > If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to (for example, on http://sqlfiddle.com/ or http://jsbin.com/) then do so—but **also copy the code into the question itself**. Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time. Use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make a live demo of inline JavaScript/HTML/CSS.

Sadly way too many people don't read or properly understand that before posting questions.