# Question with external link to code

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, external-links

Today I found this question, where the author posted an external link to the whole project, instead of putting the key pieces of code into the question (before edition):

> [Running locally working app in Azure failed with 500 error (question)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53434582/8133067)
>   [Running locally working app in Azure failed with 500 error (revisions)](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53434582/revisions)

I [advised him](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53434582/#comment93742989_53434582) to post "*Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example*", but he acted arrogantly ish:

[image]

Did I act wrong?

Comment: What you point out has already been discussed many times, the most important parts of the question should not be replaced by a link, external links serve as backup. On the other hand note that there is a lot of files and can not be shared is inaccurate, a [mcve] does not refer to sharing the project of the OP, project is different from example, the MCVE is a small example focused on the functionality, a The project has other purposes, so the OP should strive to eliminate the unnecessary part and make the resulting code coherent.

Comment: No, that seems pretty reasonable.  If he insists on 47 files, I'm going to go with the question is far too broad to be answerable.  Nobody has time to trawl through that much code to find the problem.  I see some basic debugging, but it looks like once they determined the API was working, it was time for somebody else to debug.

Comment: It also likely a duplicate of [their previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53413148/angular-asp-net-core-2-1-web-api-solution-deployed-to-azure-this-page-isn-t)

Comment: Side note: if you find similar case in the future and feel urge to edit code into the question (i.e. from JSFiddle) beware of licensing differences... While probably ok (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254757/link-only-answers-to-sites-containing-code-which-cannot-be-put-under-the-cc-by-s/254769#254769) it is better to let OP deal with code editing (unless you have solid own MCVE handy)

Comment: 47 files, please download. Yeah. Riiiiiight.

Comment: Fortunately, you still didn't get "unfriendly" in the comment section.

Comment: The problem is less that it's too many files and more that it's not a mcve (even if there are multiple files, if they're mostly auto generated/have little manual work, they can easily be made minimal by providing the command to create the project automatically)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The key mistake you made at all was commenting *instead of* voting to close it as too broad.

An OP who insists on posting tons of code hasn't done the bare minimum to isolate the problem, and there's no benefit to try and convince them that's what they need to do after they've already posted it.

Close the question. Commenting only puts the target on your back instead.

Comment: Also "Missing MCVE" would be better close reason from my point of view as discussion was around code not being either present or minimal.

Comment: I did flag the question (as off- topic > seeking debugging help), but only after the "discussion"! Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Note that the OP here (as in: @PedroGaspar) has insufficient reputation to close vote. Flagging for closure was the right call in their case IMO

Answer (score 12):

Commenting about posting a minimal verifiable example was all right (I disagree with Makoto on that one. Of course if you knew that things were going to be worse, you wouldn't have commented, but how to know?)

Sometimes people can't see clearly and dump their code, but if you ask them to reduce it, there's a chance that they comply (well, OP has 1k rep but maybe didn't ask many questions).

When OP replied "I posted a link", yes, things were starting to go downhill. Once again you acted very professional and tried to put OP in the right direction.

But OP knows better now they ask to "please download & install my application on your PC". That's a "help vampire" red flag. This person just wants some free code debugging without doing more effort.

At this point, don't comment anymore, flag/downvote/close if you have the rep, nothing good can come out.