# Problems with Stack Overflow's Creative Commons license agreement

Tags: feature-request, legal

I don't understand how someone else's code, which is probably copyrighted by default (somewhat), can somehow become your property and you put a license on it. something seems just wrong with that. if I were to post my code here, I would not want the CC license on it.
so it's a little put-offish to me as a developer...
as far as the copyrights go, I would not mind if it's just the posting engine that's copyrighted. but not my posts themselves. this has been gnawing on me for a while... please fix?

besides, compliance with the CC license requirement of attribution is not possible, since the site does not reveal who the person is (for obvious security reasons). so I guess the license has already been broken.

Comment: In Re the edit: Look in the sidebar for http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253618/if-i-use-so-code-on-my-website-how-should-i-give-attribution?

Comment: If you posted your own code, there is a high chance it would be edited or closed off anyway because you're meant to reduce a problem to its most basic components..not post entire chunks for the community to debug. The site is unlikely to change its position, for all the obvious reasons but also because your problem is far more severe in the reverse. If SA doesn't own the posted code a lot of issues with archival and display would be introduced. E.g. users requesting removal of their IP and the associated overhead of identifying whether the requester has that right or is abusing/trolling.

Comment: what? who said anything about posting code for folks to debug (most people ask for that kind of help anyway)? but this comment has nothing to do with this question.

Comment: You keep your copyright over your own content. You do not revoke this copyright, nor is it transferred to SE. They just have a license to the copy of your content that is submitted to them.

Comment: sidebar thing was interesting...

Comment: let's just say that it's unethical in the least to slap your own license on someone else's code. especially on a lot of people's code. it's rude. you wouldn't do that to your friend, would you? no.  just don't do it please.

Comment: You're putting your code on their servers.  They aren't taking it from you.  *You* are "slapping" the CC-BY-SA license on your code by posting it.

Answer (score 15):

If you don't want a code fragment to be CC-BY-SA then ***don't post it here***.

It is as simple as that.

Comment: the site is (?) already breaking the CC license by not allowing attribution. this is not lawyer advice, but I was just reading the obvious stuff in the license. how would I go about doing attribution if I don't know who user x is? there's no name, just a username. if you want someone to do attribution, there would need to be some safe way to do it... I have no clue security-wise how you would do that at the moment. thorny problem...

Comment: Strange thing to say. I've never had any trouble providing attribution for the CC content I bring in (usually Wikipedia images).

Comment: images? I thought this site was for source code. I was talking about source code. sorry for not being clear.

Comment: hmm. some people choose to put their names in for theusername, some probably most put in a handle. for instance, if you had source to post, you have a handle. so naturally I would click on avatar icon to get user info. but due to obvious security risks, a person's name is not publicised on that user page. so ho can I do attribution with just a handle? if I get permission to use the source, do I put this function by user x on stackoverflow.com? it didn't seem like this quite fit the attribution requirement for CC I would think. I don't know for sure, because I am not a lawyer. just a guess.

Comment: you didn't specify how you do that. for instance, your username or last name is all you give. Does copyright law require a first and last name for attribution, or is that part vague? I must look at it again. the only place in copyright law which mentions attribution is http://www.copyright.gov/title17/92chap1.html#106a however this seems (?) to apply to art. according to the rules this site specifies in http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/ for requirements for attribution, the rules are already violated by default because you can't *get* the person's name, just a handle.

Comment: If I put something out there under a pseudonym (like, say, a username) and people attribute the work to that pseudonym then they've done what was expected of them. Or they could link to my profile. We don't live in Earthsea and there is magic attached to true names.

Comment: @JimMichaels Did you see my answer directly below? Using a pseudonym for attribution is *explicitly* permitted by the Creative Commons license. Indeed, see [17 U.S.C. § 302 (c)](http://copyright.gov/title17/92chap3.html), titled "Anonymous Works, Pseudonymous Works, and Works Made for Hire.". i

Comment: @JimMichaels Furthermore, see [17 U.S.C § 302 (c)](http://copyright.gov/title17/92chap3.html) (Anonymous Works, Pseudonymous Works, and Works Made for Hire). Pseudonymous works are covered by much the same process as real names. It is flatly untrue that copyright law requires a first and last name for attribution, or that the CC license is violated by using pseudonyms.

Answer (score 13):

> besides, compliance with the CC license requirement of attribution is not possible, since the site does not reveal who the person is (for obvious security reasons). so I guess the license has already been broken.

This is not the case: the CC license allows attribution to a pseudonym or handle (if that is what the author prefers). From section 4c of the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/legalcode) (emphasis mine):

> You must... keep intact all copyright notices for the Work and provide, reasonable to the medium or means You are utilizing: (i) the name of the Original Author **(or pseudonym, if applicable)** if supplied...

Note that StackOverflow's policy is similar to [Wikipedia's](http://wikimediafoundation.org/wiki/Terms_of_Use#7._Licensing_of_Content), which also licenses all user-contributed content under the CC BY-SA 3.0 license, and which also allows users to publish content under a pseudonym. When you contribute an answer to Stack Overflow, you shouldn't think of it as publishing your code for others to use on your terms- you should think of it like making an edit to Wikipedia.

Comment: Absolutely right; and you didn't emphasize it, but note the last two words of your quote: *if supplied*. In other words; you don't have to provide something that wasn't provided to you.

Answer (score 8):

By posting code here, that doesn’t, through some quirk of the legal system, make it your code. Rather, we require that it is your code *before* you post it, and by posting code here, you assert that you have the right to post it here and relicense it under the license we have designated.

In practice, this isn’t usually a problem: I, at least, almost never post real code; instead, I write a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/), which, if the original code was hindered by a particular license, usually will not be. This not only works around the problems of using the original code, but often makes your question clearer by focusing only on the problematic part.

*Disclaimer: I am not a lawyer. This is not legal advice.*

Comment: Right! Side note: I know a lawyer whose disclaimer on his (very rare and broad) posts on legal topics included: **I am a lawyer. This is still not legal advice**

Comment: yuck. take the CC off. it's as I stated in Original Post. the nerve!

Comment: @JimMichaels why should we do that just for you?