# Are you allowed to use code from answers and sell your app

Tags: discussion, legal

If you are stuck when making an app and someone answers your question. Are you allowed to use their code in whole or in part.

How does the legalities work?

What if you try to contact the poster and they have no chat or email or way of contacting them and the post they put is years old?

Comment: Just so long as you give me my cut, the rest doesn't matter.

Comment: Better question: what if you write code, and you find out that someone else wrote that exact code before you. Can you use it?

Comment: I believe [section 3 of the TOS](http://stackexchange.com/legal) is the one you are interested in.

Comment: Related cross-meta post: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90538/using-code-posted-on-stackoverflow

Comment: By asking this question, you may be trying to do the right thing.  But I would love to see -- for every 10 questions like this one -- a meta question about how to reward, in cash, an SO poster with no email whose answer saved some company a large amount of time and/or money or saved their project. Google couldn't find a good match for "how can i reward someone in cash for a stack overflow answer?

Comment: See also [Should Stack Overflow get the proceeds from iPhone apps coded by answers?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/94675)

Comment: Im a single person who has now been coding in ios for about a year trying to learn how to make apps and make some money doing it. I always try to do the right thing if I can so I asked this question What does attribution is required mean? does that mean if I use a piece of code I just need to note that in my source code? Sorry Im not very good at legal stuff

Comment: @Paul Google couldn't find a good match because the answer, "find a way to contact the person and offer them cash," might be a bit too obvious to warrant any discussions. There *are* a few discussions about offering cash incentives on SE sites on various metas; I can't dig them up right now, but they were very poorly received (for many good reasons).

Comment: @JasonC Yes, I'm aware of a few of those. I tried to turn my comment into a meta-SO question a few hours ago, and cited two of the other meta questions regarding money as anti-examples. I was more interested in monetary "Random Acts of Kindness" (wow, you saved us, here's $1,000 and a nice letter from the CEO/VP) associated with SO Q&A rather than "Hey, I still need an answer, how about $20" (which is covered  explicitly in another meta as still not being enough for a true expert but instead inviting strife and poor quality guesses).

Comment: @JoshCaswell, now I really want to see a bot that scrapes code from SO and uses it to generate apps.

Comment: I think this post answers this: [If I use SO code on my website, how should I give attribution?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253618/if-i-use-so-code-on-my-website-how-should-i-give-attribution)