# SO Content: cc by-sa 3.0 with attribution (not?) required

Tags: discussion, support, copycat-sites

As per [the answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253622/2173917) on this post by Bill, I think, any SO content appearing outside SO needs to

- Give credit to the author
- Have link back to the original post

However, today, I came across [this site](http://www.codedisqus.com/) making blatant copy of SO content without making any sort of attribution.

To verify my statement:

1. Copy any question text in that link in full
2. Make a [Google](http://www.google.com) search
3. See for yourself.

*IANAL*, but IMHO, it's a violation of the copyright.

What should be (our) next course of action?

Comment: OK, what is the possible reason for downvote? Is it a dupe? I [din't find any](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=codedisqus).

Comment: Well, there are duplicates. Just not mentioning that specific site. As to whether that was the reason for the downvote, I'm no mind-reader.

Comment: @Deduplicator well, possibly you're right. Let me report it through proper channel. :-)

Comment: The footer on their results page is another classic. "© 2014 codedisqus.com, All rights reserved   user contributions licensed under cc by-sa 3.0 with attribution required.   Any advice please contact us"

Comment: @BilltheLizard Yep. :-)