# How is ShareAlike interpreted in case of Stack Overflow content?

Tags: support, attribution, licensing

## Background

Stack Overflow content is under "CC-BY-SA" license. This means that you can:

- Commercially use and share the content (no NC is applied to license)
- You can adapt the content to your needs

but

- You should attribute the original author (Q and A) clearly and fairly (BY)
- if you remix, transform or build upon the material you must distribute your contributions under the same license as the original. (SA) [source](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)

## Question

1. My main question is how ShareAlike (SA) is interpreted in case of a commercial app that uses code from SO and has changed it slightly to fit the purpose and is publicly available (say on Play Store)?
2. A slightly unrelated question to the main topic: in terms of attribution do we need to acknowledge the attribution on the final product too? like on About page or ...?

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/) but couldn't find the answer to this question.

Comment: Reason being, the answer talks about any code, not just websites: "If you're just *using* bits of code you found on Stack Overflow to get your program to work, then you're using the site as it was intended to be used. The attribution doesn't need to be publicly displayed, but you should put a URL in your source code comments so that you and anyone else who reads your code can go back to the original source if they need to." -- [Bill the Lizard](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253622/7795130), emphasis in original.