# Another Stack Overflow Attribution Question

Tags: discussion, attribution, creative-commons

I've just learned about the fact that all content posted on Stack Overflow is listed under a Creative Commons license. There are many questions out there on ALL the forum platforms about this, but here I'm going to add another.

1. If a user gives explicit "public domain" status to a contribution or all their contributions, is this legit or is this more of a mistaken belief like when people share copyrighted content on YouTube with the whole "No copyright infringement intended" disclaimer?
2. I am designing a commercial website, still very beginning stages and I'm honestly learning along the way. But I received some JavaScript help on a single-page tabular navbar via Stack Overflow. I copied and pasted the answer as-is. My understanding is that now I need to attribute the question and contributor. Is this correct? If so, can I legally do that on a separate "Attributions" page of my website WITHOUT having any indication of this on the navbar itself?

My question was probably a genuinely dumb question, but I wound up completely changing the JavaScript code due to just one answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/66340753/14278839.  I also just wound up copying and pasting the improved code from the answer.

I just want to make sure I'm in compliance with expectations, but not overthinking everything.

Comment: You’re asking two questions and at least one is a duplicate: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253618/6083675

Comment: I think it's anyone's right to double license their stuff. If they explicitly say on their profile that they're licensing anything under public domain, you just need to give them attribution. I do not think you need to link to the site nor any license. I also do not believe you need to link to them on the product itself, unless you're selling your solution which includes the code you used.